# Laravel CSRF error

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I am learning laravel and I have just created a middleware with a very little session work. but I am getting below error:

> FatalThrowableError in VerifyCsrfToken.php line 136: Call to a member
>   function setCookie() on null

Here is the middleware:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Middleware;

use Closure;

class Adminlogin {

    public function handle($request, Closure $next) {
        echo 1;
        if (!$request->session()->has('userid')) {
            return view('admin.auth.login');
        }
        return $next($request);
    }

}
```

Comment: That is core code or laravel 5.3

Comment: Hi @Haren...you can try with `return response()->view('admin.auth.login');`

Comment: @mopo922 no.. I have not changed anything. this is inside vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/Middleware/VerifyCsrfToken.php line 136:

Comment: @Hackerman your solution perfectly working fine.. can you please state it as answer and tell me how it worked :) ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this scenario `response()->view()` returns the specified view with the status code 200, but you are able to modify the response in many ways.

> **From the documentation**: If you need control over the response's status and headers but also need to return a view as the response's content, you should use the view method: https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/responses

```
return response()
        ->view('hello', $data, 200)
        ->header('Content-Type', $type);
```

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't return a view from your `middleware`. Instead, try redirecting to a route that returns that view.

Like -

```
return redirect()->route('login');
```